# How to update UI of a hidden fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a hidden fragment (hidden by calling FragmentTransaction.hide()). I want to update a list view on this fragment when it is hidden.
The issue is that, since the fragment's visibility is set to GONE when it is hidden, it won't get measure/layout called. So the UI will not be updated until FragmentTransaction.show() is called for this fragment.
Is there any way to update the hidden fragment's UI without FragmentTransaction.show() being called for it?

Comment: Why do you want to spend the user's CPU, the user's battery, and the user's RAM on updating a UI that cannot be seen and might *never* be seen (depending on what the user does with their device)? Wait until the fragment is going to be seen again, *then* update the UI's contents.

Comment: I want to speed up the navigation to the fragment, which is very important to our product.

Comment: What makes you think that what you are proposing will speed up the navigation to the fragment? What **specifically** is slow?

Comment: Updating all the item views in the list view is slow.

Comment: That is not very specific. Updating a smattering of widgets from cached data will take a few milliseconds. You need to determine **specifically** what is slow, down to the individual Java statement. Then, figure out how to address that **specific** problem. For example, if the slow work is in updating `ImageViews` with new images, make sure that your image cache has the right images, so that when your UI does display, it can be done quickly.

Comment: I ended up with calling measure and layout on the root view of the hidden fragment to force layout.